# How to change country in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac

How do I change the exit node country for TorBrowser on Mac OS X? I can't find a file called "torrc" on my Mac.

Answer (score 8):

Try to take a look at Settings->Advanced, it appears to be in Applications/TorBrowser_en-US/Library/Vidalia/torrc and add this :

```
ExitNodes {us}
StrictNodes 1
GeoIPExcludeUnknown 1
AllowSingleHopCircuits 0
```

Comment: On the latest version, and for some websites its not working...
https://gitlab.torproject.org/tpo/core/tor/-/issues/40167
In my case I enter the site with the correct exit node, but then it refreshes with another.. even when i strict to 1.

Comment: "Try to take a look at Settings->Advanced" Where are you seeing the path? I'm on 11.0.9 and can't see it.

Answer (score 8):

There's an [entry](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#torrc) in the Tor FAQ that has a few more details on where to find the `torrc` file on different platforms.

> If you installed Tor Browser, look for
>   Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc inside your Tor Browser directory.
>   On OS X, you must right-click or command-click on the Tor Browser
>   icon, and select "Show Package Contents" before the Tor Browser
>   directories become visible.

That is no longer the location.  It was a problem to have one torrc for all users.  So now (version 6.0.5) it is at
~/Library/Application\ Support/TorBrowser-Data/Tor/torrc
There is still one inside the app, but it is apparently ignored.

To add to what Alexey said, the FAQ entry detailing further node-related config is [here](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#ChooseEntryExit), and the official list of 2-letter country codes can be found on Wikipedia, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements). (Substitute one of these for the `us` mentioned in Alexey's response.)

Comment: "So now (version 6.0.5) it is at"
Seems like it has moved again.